# How To Overflow Text Above Divs - Even if Parent Div Is 0% Width

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4, and I have three divs horizontally stacked in a row. The three divs are of varying percentage widths. Often the center div is 0%.

However, I want to display text from that 0% div every single time, no matter what. I can not seem to get the text within that div to
a) Show up above the other divs in every situation
b) Center the text so that the overflow extends *equally* from the center of the 0% div.

I'd really prefer to not have to do this using a left/right positioning, because the width of the text is variable.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row d-flex">                        
     <div class="float-left bg-info" style="width: 80%;"></div>
     <div class="text-nowrap text-center" style="width: 1%;">32.34 in.</div>    
     <div class="float-right bg-warning" style="width: 19%;"></div>
</div>
```

And here is a BootPly:
https://www.bootply.com/IurHhOsuf5

Is there a way to make this text stay on top?

Here's an image of what it's currently doing:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eTZb.png)

And here's what it *should* look like:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXoej.png)

Thanks everybody!

Comment: There's no css other than the default css from Bootstrap 4.1. The BootPly link should have it included.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Progress Bar from `Bootstrap4`?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progress" style="width: 80%;"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-light text-dark align-items-center" role="progress" 
        style="width: 1%; z-index:10;">32.34 in.</div>
    <div class="progress-bar bg-warning" role="progress" style="width: 19%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Couple key points here:

1. You need to use `z-index` to make the text go on top of the progress bars.
2. By default, progress bar's flex direction is set to column. In order to center the text, you need to set `align-items: center;`. Or you can use bootstrap class `align-items-center`.

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/aq9Laaew/290113/